# -> Arrow operator with Arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

Can you use the arrow operator with an array of type struct.  For example:

```
struct {
char *foo;
} fooArray[10];

fooArray[0]->foo = ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to use `fooArray[0].foo`.

`fooArray` is a pointer that happens to point to the first element of an array. Using the `[]` is dereferencing that pointer at the given element so once applied it's no longer a pointer and the `->` operator cannot be applied since that operator does both dereferencing and accessing a struct member.

Comment: I've been told off for saying that an array type is "a pointer that happens to point to the first element of an array", though I assume it does act like a pointer with the -> operator such that you can do `fooArray->foo`?

Answer (score 4):

Remember the value of `fooArray` by itself is a pointer. You can dereference the pointer, add to it, ...

```
fooArray->foo; /* same as fooArray[0].foo */
(fooArray+3)->foo; /* same as fooArray[3].foo */
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use array operator(for accessing data members) only on pointers, fooArray[0] is not a pointer to struct, If you want to use it you take address of it and use it like

```
(&fooArray[0])->foo="hello";
```

Or declare pointer/array of pointers to struct and allocate memory to it ..like

```
fooArray* a=new fooArray();
a->foo="hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remember that `a->b` is a shorthand for `(*a).b`. Keeping this in mind should help you tackle any situation. I.e, in your case `fooArray[0]->foo` means `(*fooarray[0]).foo`, but `fooarray[0]` isn't a pointer (it's a struct), so you can not dereference it. Hence it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not in your case because you are accessing a struct (not a pointer to a struct) when you use

```
fooArray[0]
```

The compiler would let you know about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Has to be a pointer. E.g. this is OK syntax-wise (but it will segfault unless fooArray is assigned):

```
int main ()
{
struct {
char *foo;
}* fooArray[10];

fooArray[0]->foo = "hallo";
}
```

Comment: It's not assigned. I am just demonstrating the syntax. It says so in the post.